# MVC5 custom principal not IsInRole not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Since I upgraded my project to MVC5 in VS2012 the Custom principal I implemented isn't working anymore.

The principal:

```
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public Boolean IsInRole(String role)
    {
        return ((CustomIdentity)Identity).User.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role);
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public CustomPrincipal(UserSession userSession)
    {
        Identity = new CustomIdentity(userSession);
    }
}
```

Custom identity:

```
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public String AuthenticationType
    {
        get
        {
            return "CustomAuthentication";
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }

    public User User { get; private set; }
    public UserSession UserSession { get; private set; }

    public CustomIdentity(UserSession userSession)
    {
        User = userSession.User;
        UserSession = userSession;
        Name = userSession.User.UserName;
        IsAuthenticated = userSession.User.IsApproved && !userSession.User.IsDisabled && !userSession.User.IsLockedOut;
    }
}
```

How I set the User:

```
var principal = new CustomPrincipal(userSession);
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

The `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attribute doesn't work anymore, neither does `var a = HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrator");`

When I place a breakpoint at `IsInRole` it never reaches there, but the constructed is called and `HttpContext.Current.User` does contain the `CustomPrincipal` object.

What could be changed or wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem, upgraded an existing MVC4 project in VS2012. The User.IsInRole doesn't seem to work at all in MVC5... [This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099722/role-management-in-asp-mvc-5-microsoft-aspnet-identity) seems to describe the same problem.

Comment: But is not giving the solution :) I had to revert back to MVC4 because I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, you are right. In my case it seems the IsInRole is not working only on localhost (Roles are defined in Active Directory), if I deploy to a test server (w2k8) it seems to work again. My local machine is w8.1. Also if I loop through the roles not all are returned. If I find something I will let you know!

Comment: BTW it does not seem to be a MVC problem, rather a w8.1 in a Winforms application I am having the same issue, where it did work in w8.

Comment: I didn't try to deploy it but I am still using W7 with VS2012.

Comment: Did you try adding the following in your global.asax: 
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() {
            Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(User);
        }